# How to use scoped dependency injection in singleton

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection

I have a scoped service (lets it be `UserContext`, that contain user IP). It service I try to inject in another services (let's call them `ProfileManager` and `LogerProvider`).

In my controller at startup, I added them like so:

```
service
   .AddTransient(ILogerProvider, LogerProvider)()
   .AddSingleton<IProfileManager, ProfileManager)()
   .AddScoped<IUserContext, UserContext>()
```

Class `LogerProvider` contain `UserContext` inject:

```
class LogerProvider: ILogerProvider
{
   private readonly IUserContext _userContext;

   public LogerProvider(IUserContext userContext)
   {
      _userContext = userContext;
   }
}
```

Class `ProfileManager` contain `LogerProvider` inject:

```
class ProfileManager: IProfileManager
{
   private readonly ILogerProvider _logerProvider;

   public ProfileManager(ILogerProvider logerProvider)
   {
      _logerProvider = logerProvider;
   }
}
```

And when i try to run my program i got error:

```
(Inner Exception #1) System.InvalidOperationException: Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: IProfileManager Lifetime: Singleton ImplementationType: IProfileManager': Cannot consume scoped service 'IUserContext' from singleton 'IProfileManager'.
```

I found that i can just change lifetime of `ProfileManager` just make it transient. But i need to use this service like singleton. So a question: how i can realize dependency injection saved lifetime of services how i typed at the beginning of the text?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to manually create a scope and consume it, to do so you'll need to inject the `IServiceProvider` into your singleton service and then call [`IServiceCollection.CreateScope`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.serviceproviderserviceextensions.createscope?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0)

```cs
public class ProfileManager : IProfileManager
{
    private readonly IServiceProvider _services;

    public ProfileManager(IServiceProvider services)
    {
        _services = services;
    }

    public void DoSomething()
    {
        using (var scope = _services.CreateScope())
        {
            var logger = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ILogerProvider>();
        }
    }
}
```

Sidenote: You may want to rethink the lifetimes and scopes of your services if you find yourself repeating this pattern again and again

Answer (score 3):

I would strongly advise against storing any sort of user context information in a singleton class, for security reasons. If you do it wrong, users will be able to see each others' data.

If your logger needs user context information, have the caller pass it in and store it only as a local variable for the duration of the method call. Never store it as a member variable.

```
class LogerProvider: ILogerProvider
{    
    public void LogMessage(IUserContext userContext, string message)
    {
        //Write to logs, including user context information
    }
}
```

This will also prevent anyone from trying to log anything when there is no user context, as it will be obvious to them that they don't have one of the necessary arguments. If your logger has a dependency on user context then its methods should not be called when there isn't one.

If you don't want to burden the caller with the extra argument, consider using the [ThreadPrincipal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/security/principal-and-identity-objects) to store your user context.

Answer (score 0):

To be able to use scoped services within a singleton, you must create a scope manually. A new scope can be created by injecting an `IServiceScopeFactory` into your singleton service (the `IServiceScopeFactory` is itself a singleton, which is why this works). The `IServiceScopeFactory` has a `CreateScope` method, which is used for creating new scope instances.

```
public class MySingletonService
{
  private readonly IServiceScopeFactory _serviceScopeFactory;

  public MySingletonService(IServiceScopeFactory serviceScopeFactory)
  {
    _serviceScopeFactory = serviceScopeFactory;
  }

  public void Execute()
  {
    using var scope = _serviceScopeFactory.CreateScope()
    var myScopedService = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<IMyScopedService>();    
    myScopedService.DoSomething();
  }
}
```

The created scope has its own `IServiceProvider`, which you can access to resolve your scoped services.

It is important to make sure that the scope only exists for as long as is necessary, and that it is properly disposed of once you have finished with it. This is to avoid any issues of captive dependencies. Therefore, I would recommend:

- Only define the scope within the method that you intend to use it. It might be tempting to assign it to a field for reuse elsewhere in the singleton service, but again this will lead to captive dependencies.
- Wrap the scope in a using statement. This will ensure that the scope is properly disposed of once you have finished with it.

In short, `IServiceProvider.CreateScope()` and `IServiceScopeFactory.CreateScope()` are identical (in non-scoped context even instances of `IServiceProvider` and `IServiceScopeFactory` are identical).

But here is a little difference between these abstractions
`IServiceProvider`'s lifetime can be Scoped. But `IServiceScopeFactory`'s lifetime is always Singleton.