# Multiple contexts in a Singleton service

Tags: c#, dependency-injection

Currently i'm designing a logger service to log `HttpRequests` made by `HttpClient`.

This logger service is `Singleton` and i want to have `scoped` contexts inside it.

Here's my logger:

```cs
public Logger
{
    public LogContext Context { get; set; }    

    public void LogRequest(HttpRequestLog log)
    {  
        context.AddLog(log);
    }
}
```

I'm using the logger inside a `DelegatingHandler`:

```
private readonly Logger logger;

public LoggingDelegatingHandler(Logger logger)
{
  this.logger = logger;
}

protected async override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
   await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
   this.logger.LogRequest(new HttpRequestog());
}
```

Then when i make some request using `HttpClient`, i want to have the logs for this specific call:

```cs
private void InvokeApi()
{
  var logContext = new LogContext();
  this.Logger.LogContext = logContext;
  var httpClient = httpClientFactory.CreateClient(CustomClientName);
  await httpClient.GetAsync($"http://localhost:11111");

  var httpRequestLogs = logContext.Logs;
}
```

The problem is, it works but it's not thread safe. If i have parallel executions of `InvokeApi`, the `context` will not be the correct.

> How can i have a attached context for each execution properly?

I'm registering the HttpClient like this:

```cs
services.AddSingleton<Logger>();
services.AddHttpClient(CentaurusHttpClient)
        .ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler((c) => new HttpClientHandler()
        {
             AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate,
        })
        .AddHttpMessageHandler(sp => new LoggingDelegatingHandler(sp.GetRequiredService<Logger>()));
```

I'm testing this piece of code using this:

```cs
public void Test_Parallel_Logging()
{
    Random random = new Random();

    Action test = async () =>
    {
        await RunScopedAsync(async scope =>
        {
            IServiceProvider sp = scope.ServiceProvider;

            var httpClientFactory = sp.GetRequiredService<IHttpClientFactory>();
            using (var context = new HttpRequestContext(sp.GetRequiredService<Logger>()))
            {
                try
                {
                    var httpClient = httpClientFactory.CreateClient();
                    await httpClient.GetAsync($"http://localhost:{random.Next(11111, 55555)}");
                }
                catch (HttpRequestException ex)
                {
                    Output.WriteLine("count: " + context?.Logs?.Count);
                }
            }
        });
    };

    Parallel.Invoke(new Action[] { test, test, test });
}
```

Comment: What type of app is this? web, windows forms, console, etc. It almost sounds like you need a transient or request scoped wrapper around your singleton logger and the context would be on there. If a non-web app, there's some form of thread local storage you could use. The wrapper could then pass the context in to the actual logger during the log calls.

Comment: You are calling an async method and therefore need to await its call, make your method async as well. Read more about async: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/

Comment: It's a web project. But will run a background service using `Hangfire` server.

Comment: As a quick fix I would tried to use [`AsyncLocal`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.asynclocal-1?view=net-5.0) as long term - I would think about refactoring the Logger and injecting it as per request or some other approach (maybe using one of the existing logging library)

Comment: @Zokka yes, you're right creating the example i forgot this. I edited the question and added my unit test.

Comment: @GuruStron what a hack! It worked.

Comment: @BrunoWarmling glad it helped. Still I recommend considering rewriting tho whole thing somehow)

Comment: Relevant: [How to use scoped dependency in singleton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67631673/how-to-use-scoped-dependency-injection-in-singleton)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This logger service is Singleton and i want to have scoped contexts inside it.

The `Logger` has a singleton lifetime, so its `LogContext` property also has a singleton lifetime.

For the kind of scoped data you're wanting, `AsyncLocal<T>` is an appropriate solution. I tend to prefer following a "provider"/"consumer" pattern similar to React's Context, although the more common name in the .NET world for "consumer" is "accessor". In this case, you could make the `Logger` itself into the provider, though I generally try to keep it a separate type.

IMO this is most cleanly done by providing your own explicit scope, and *not* tying into the "scope" lifetime of your DI container. It's possible to do it with DI container scopes but you end up with some weird code like resolving producers and then doing nothing with them - and if a future maintainer removes (what appears to be) unused injected types, then the accessors break.

So I recommend your own scope, as such:

```
public Logger
{
  private readonly AsyncLocal<LogContext> _context = new();

  public void LogRequest(HttpRequestLog log)
  {
    var context = _context.Value;
    if (context == null)
      throw new InvalidOperationException("LogRequest was called without anyone calling SetContext");
    context.AddLog(log);
  }

  public IDisposable SetContext(LogContext context)
  {
    var oldValue = _context.Value;
    _context.Value = context;
    // I use Nito.Disposables; replace with whatever Action-Disposable type you have.
    return new Disposable(() => _context.Value = oldValue);
  }
}
```

Usage (note the explicit scoping provided by `using`):

```
private void InvokeApi()
{
  var logContext = new LogContext();
  using (this.Logger.SetContext(logContext))
  {
    var httpClient = httpClientFactory.CreateClient(CustomClientName);
    await httpClient.GetAsync($"http://localhost:11111");
    var httpRequestLogs = logContext.Logs;
  }
}
```

Comment: That's look so much better. I'm just thinking that, if another person want to this HttpClient and don't provide a context to the logger, an exception will be thrown in execution time. In a perfect world, it would be better if it produces a syntax error, don't you think that?

Comment: @BrunoWarmling: If you mean a compile-time error, then yes, that would be ideal. But it's generally more work. E.g., you could create a derived type of `HttpClient` that overrides all virtual "do the request" methods with its own call to `SetContext`. That would enforce correct producer usage, at the cost of some complexity. You'd have to modify `HttpRequestLog` to enforce correct consumer usage. You may end up subtyping the entire HttpClient pipeline and factory system.