# .NET Blazor & scoped dependency injected DB context

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, entity-framework-core, blazor-server-side

###### Problem:

We have a Blazor server app with a DevExpress grid component, showing data directly from the DB. We want all the operations - filtering, grouping, etc. - to take place on the DB layer, that’s why we don’t use a Service layer to fetch the data, rather we hook directly onto the DB context.
Let’s say we have 2 users, looking at the same grid, each in his own browser (that implicitly means 2 different SignalR connections). User 1 changes the state, but user 2 isn’t aware of that, even if he refreshes the grid. Only when user 2 refreshes the page (F5) are the differences shown.

###### Explanation:

DB contexts are “scoped DI” by default. In a classic HTTP request-response architecture, that means that for the duration of a request, one and the same instance of the DB context is provided by the DI to all who request it. In the example above, data would be refreshed, because each request will instantiate a new DB context.
In a Blazor app, things are different. DB context in our case is not refreshed with each WEB request. Actually, the term ‘request’ doesn’t even exist in SignalR (WebSocket) and WebAssembly. So, what happens in our example? As long as the SignalR connection is alive, user 2 has the same instance of the DB context. If another user changes state in his own instance of the context, these changes aren’t propagated to other context instances. Roughly, this means that a ‘scoped’ DB context actually becomes a ‘singleton’ (well, almost, singleton in the scope of a user / session / signalR connection).

###### Links:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/dependency-injection
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/blazor-server-ef-core
- https://www.thinktecture.com/blazor/dependency-injection-scopes-in-blazor/

###### Thoughts:

- Our service layer is stateless, so it isn't a problem. DB contexts are problematic
- Blazor doesn’t have a concept of a ‘scoped’ service

  - ‘Scoped’ is actually a singleton in the scope of a single connection
  - ‘Singleton’ provides the same service for all the connections
- There is an [approximation of a scoped service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-6.0#utility-base-component-classes-to-manage-a-di-scope), scoped to the ‘component’ level

  - Each razor component will use the same instances in its lifetime
  - But this lifetime can be long lived nonetheless
  - [Another, similar approximation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/blazor-server-ef-core?view=aspnetcore-6.0#scope-to-the-component-lifetime)
- If truth be told, things are pretty similar to the classic request-response architecture: if 2 requests would happen at exactly the same time, there would be 2 DB context instances with different states. This surely can happen, but the probability of it is low, so it’s not such a problem
- Having a ‘transient’ DB context also isn’t OK

  - we want our API (service layer) methods to be a “unit of work” (1 API - 1 DB transaction)
  - one API can call multiple BL functions, each in a separate ServiceBL class - those should have the same DB context instances

###### Solutions:

- Scoped is already treated almost the same as a singleton. What if we would register DB contexts as singletons?

  - Sounds like a bad idea - everybody would use one long-lived instance, it would/could present a bottleneck, what about thread safety?
  - "EF Core does not support multiple parallel operations being run on the same context instance"
- ‘Page refresh‘ in the right places can be a substitute for ‘scopes’

  - await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("location.reload");
  - NavigationManager.NavigateTo(NavigationManager.Uri, forceLoad: true);
- When the ‘refresh data grid’ button is clicked, we can create a new instance of the DB context

  - This is only a solution for this specific case, though. The underlying problem still exists, multiple users have different instances of DB contexts which will sooner or later blow up in our faces
- API methods are our unit-of-work. We could manually create a DI scope, use it for the duration of the API and then dispose of it. But that would mean we would have to bubble the services (at least DB context) down to each and every class that would need them :/

Any ideas would be much appreciated

Comment: FWIW using a service layer with CQRS does not exclude doing filtering, grouping, searching, ect. on the DB layer and seems like it would. Alternative you could manually create and destroy scopes as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67631673/9363973)

Comment: Even using a service layer instead of directly hooking to DB context would not fix the problem, it would only move it somewhere else. As for the "manually creating and disposing DI scopes" - my last solution describes exactly that. With it come more problems. Imagine having 2 service classes, BlogService & PostService, each with its own logic. 1 unit-of-work action could comprise of both these services doing some work, so they should get the same instance of DB context from the DI. I can't imagine a nice, layered architecture + manually creating DI scopes to fit into it.

Comment: The DbContext is your Unit-of-Work, not a database connection. It seems the real problem is how DI and "services" are used. Although I think that, as a scoped service, a DbContext instance will be shared among other services with the same scope. If you want to be sure, you need to pass it as a method parameter, not wait for the DI to pass it in the constructor.

Comment: A DI container isn't necessary for layering or even inversion of control. The classes shouldn't depend on its existence.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos "The DbContext is your Unit-of-Work" & "a DbContext instance will be shared among other services with the same scope" -> both of these are absolutely true. Maybe it would be useful if I shed a little bit more light on our architecture, even though I think it's pretty common stuff, nothing out of the ordinary. We have a 'web' project and a 'service' project. Web handles GUI stuff and only forwards the calls to the service layer where all of the business logic resides.

Comment: So lets say we have a Blog and a Post Service. If a user e.g. upvotes a post, we want to change the state of 2 entities, each within its own service class - for instance, PostService will `IncreaseVoteCount()` and BlogService will `UpdateBlog()` (imagine that these BL methods aren't trivial, so they are actually needed). In other words, we want to be able to call one API method that delegates the work between multiple service classes, but all of them should work on the same instance of DbContext and in the end, all or nothing should be saved to DB.

Comment: Everything stated above is not a problem in a classic architecture, where a DI scope has a lifetime of a single HTTP request. Also, there is no problem in Blazor, if you scope to the 'component' level and you actually frequently switch between different components so new DI scopes are created. But, if one component is all that you need and you stay on that page and only refresh the state of that component, no additional DI scopes will be created so the DbContext will always be the same - singleton.

Answer (score 1):

This MSDN article: [ASP.NET Core Blazor Server with Entity Framework Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/blazor-server-ef-core) describes two possible solutions:

- Use a context factory to create a DbContext for the lifetime of a single method
- Scope the DbContext to the lifetime of some component

## Context Factory

Set it up through

```
builder.Services.AddDbContextFactory<ContactContext>(opt => ...);
```

And then use it with an injected `IDbContextFactory<ContactContext>`

```
internal Task SomeMethod()
{ 
    using var context = DbFactory.CreateDbContext();
 
    // use context
    
    await context.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

## Component lifetime

The same factory setup is needed, and then in the component:

```
@implements IDisposable
@inject IDbContextFactory<ContactContext> DbFactory
```

Define a `Context` and make sure it is disposed at the end (that's why it must implement IDisposable):

```
public void Dispose()
{
    Context?.Dispose();
}
```

And make sure you create it at the start:

```
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    Context = DbFactory.CreateDbContext();

    // ...
}
```

---

And if per-method is too fine grained and per-component too coarse grained (especially as components can be very long lived in Blazor), then you will need to find (or probably have found by now) a middle ground:

- Keep the `IDbContextFactory`, and
- Explicitly handle the lifetime of the resulting context, passing it along to methods that need to work with that context.

Comment: At the time, I tried both of these approaches, none of them really solve the problem generally. Scoping the DbContext to the lifetime of a component seems like it would be the obvious answer, but (as already stated in the original question) the lifetimes of Blazor components can be very long lived, so essentially this can behave similarly to a singleton.

Comment: As for creating a DbContext for the lifetime of a single method: in my opinion, this only works in really simple use cases, where your BL is trivial. Now imagine having 2 service classes, BlogService & PostService, each with its own logic. 1 unit-of-work action could comprise of both these services doing some work, so they should get the same instance of DB context from the DI. The question is, how can we achieve that in a nice, layered architecture...

Comment: On the contrary, single-method or request is the way DbContext was designed to work, to make layering and transaction logic easier by using optimistic concurrency. It's a Unit-of-Work already, not a database connection, and doesn't even open one until it has to store all pending changes in a single internal transaction.